# How to solve this error of git global config on windows?

Tags: git

Recently, I have been using "github desktop". But when I want to change some config, I find one problem. There will always be a error in my git global config file after using cmd line `git config --global --list`, as shown below.

```
error: cannot spawn more: No such file or directory
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
core.pager=more
```

I have already made sure that this error is not about core.pager, because I tried to solve it to use `git config --global core.pager "less"` and `git config --global core.pager "more"`, neither of them work. So is there any solution for this error on windows?

Comment: There should be a copy of less distributed with git itself, perhaps you need to reinstall or repair your git installation?

Comment: If you don't have `more` installed, but don't have `less` either, neither of these will work. However, `more` should be installed even on Windows by default; check your `PATH`.

Comment: as @tiplee said : check your PATH. What shell are you using ? `git-bash` ? powershell ? cmd ?